# USB Capable Outlets in the middle of a circuit

Tags: receptacle

I want to install a USB capable outlet in the middle of a run but every USB capable outlet seems to only have two screws plus the ground. Can I install both whites and reds on the appropriate screws?

Comment: Usually not unless it is a better grade(50 cent compared 5 dollars).  Can use a pigtail(wires connected together) to connect to outlet.

Comment: @crip659 write that up as an answer

Comment: You're not required to use the screws *on the receptacle* to make splices, in fact, in some cases (like ground) this is forbidden!  Make sure you are not downgrading from GFCI to plain (there are ways to work around this if you need GFCI but want USB too).

Comment: Aside - these are permanently energised small PSUs inside your wall, an excellent reason to install decent quality ones.

Answer (score 8):

Most screws on devices are only made to hold one wire/connector, against code to add more than one wire on these.

Some better made devices have screws that can hold two wires.  Check first.

If wanting to use a device with only screw per wire, you can use a pigtail, where two or more wires are connected with a wire nut. One wire connected to the device and connected by wire nut to the other wire/s.

Comment: Outlets that can take more than one wire under a screw typically have some kind of clamping mechanism rather than just a screw to put a wire loop under.